# How to use pf to route this scenario

Tags: macos, network, firewall, pfctl

*Scenario*

I need `pf` on a Mac to do this: redirecting any connections to localhost:8080 to a public domain.

--> localhost:8080 --> public domain

*Example*

The public domain is hosting a nginx server. On my laptop, if I use `curl -H'Host: public.com' localhost:8080` then:

1. The server behind that public domain must receive a connection with correct Host header - public.com not localhost
2. curl returns nginx default page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as written this questions is about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [help]

Comment: @Allan The question is **not** off-topic since pf is part of newer macOS versions.

Comment: @klanomath `pf` has been included since Lion so it’s not newer, but it’s also included with all versions of BSD, Debian, QNX, Solaris and used in some firewall appliances - pfSense.  What platform is the OP on?

Comment: Checking his [stackoverflow profile (& questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5739790/tran-triet) it's probably a Mac & macOS...

Comment: Thanks @klanomath for the clarification. I put this question here because I saw that a lot of pf questions are asked here and that I want to do this on a MacOS. I'll update that part in the question.